# How to change the background color of an item in a list when using the function List.generate in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

function description: when an item is clicked, change the background color of this item 。

I defined the variable color in the `List.generate` function and used the `setState` function in `onTapDown` to modify this value, but it has no effect. what should I do?

my code is as follows

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Homepage> {
  final titles = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"];
  final subtitles = [
    "我去，额度这么高？",
    "XX，你上次给我兑换的烤箱还不错哦",
    "抱歉，我觉得我们不是很合适",
    "邻居你好，你家的租户最近有点吵"
  ];
  final date = ["昨天 18:08", "星期二", "7月21日", "7月19日"];
  final avatar = [
    "WechatIMG325.jpeg",
    "WechatIMG326.jpeg",
    "WechatIMG327.jpeg",
    "WechatIMG328.jpeg"
  ];
  // final icons = [Icons.ac_unit, Icons.access_alarm, Icons.access_time];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ...List.generate(titles.length, (index) {
          var color = Colors.white;
          return GestureDetector(
            behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
            onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) {
              setState(() {
                color = Colors.grey;
              });
              debugPrint("presed GestureDetector");
            },
            onTapUp: (TapUpDetails details) {
              setState(() {
                color = Colors.white;
              });
              debugPrint("presed GestureDetector");
            },
            child: Container(
              color: color,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
              child: Row(children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 50,
                  child: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                      child: Image.asset("assets/images/${avatar[index]}",
                          height: 50, width: 50),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                //const SizedBox(width: 10),
                IntrinsicWidth(
                  child: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          titles[index],
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 5),
                        Text(
                          subtitles[index],
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15,
                            color: Colors.black54,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
            ),
          );
        }),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try  this code will help you to start in OOP and make model to data in your app and you can add any thing to class like Icon ....

```
        class FakeData {
    final String title, subTitle, avatar, data;
    bool onTapDown;

   FakeData(
   {required this.title,
   this.onTapDown = false,
   required this.subTitle,
   required this.avatar,
   required this.data});
    }
```

this class collect data app and state for all item

```
        class HomeState extends State<Homepage> {
      final fakeData = [
        FakeData(
          title: 'AAA',
          subTitle: '我去，额度这么高？',
          avatar: "WechatIMG325.jpeg",
          data: "昨天 18:08",
        ),
        FakeData(
          title: 'BBB',
          subTitle: "XX，你上次给我兑换的烤箱还不错哦",
          avatar: "WechatIMG326.jpeg",
          data: "星期二",
        ),
        FakeData(
          title: 'CCC',
          subTitle: "抱歉，我觉得我们不是很合适",
          avatar: "WechatIMG327.jpeg",
          data: "7月21日",
        ),
        FakeData(
          title: 'DDD',
          subTitle: "邻居你好，你家的租户最近有点吵",
          avatar: "WechatIMG328.jpeg",
          data: "7月19日",
        ),
      ];
    
      // final icons = [Icons.ac_unit, Icons.access_alarm, Icons.access_time];
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Column(
          children: [
            ...List.generate(fakeData.length, (index) {
              return GestureDetector(
                behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
                onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) {
                  setState(() {
                    fakeData[index].onTapDown = !fakeData[index].onTapDown;
                  });
                  debugPrint("presed GestureDetector");
                },
                onTapUp: (TapUpDetails details) {
                  setState(() {
                    fakeData[index].onTapDown = !fakeData[index].onTapDown;
                  });
                  debugPrint("presed GestureDetector");
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: fakeData[index].onTapDown ? Colors.grey : Colors.white,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                  child: Row(children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 50,
                      child: Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10),
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                          child: Image.asset(
                              "assets/images/${fakeData[index].avatar}",
                              height: 50,
                              width: 50),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    //const SizedBox(width: 10),
                    IntrinsicWidth(
                      child: Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              fakeData[index].title,
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                              ),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(height: 5),
                            Text(
                              fakeData[index].subTitle,
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 15,
                                color: Colors.black54,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]),
                ),
              );
            }),
          ],
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `color` needs to be outside the `build` method of the `State`, this code will reset the color to `Colors.white` on each build.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Homepage> {
  final titles = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"];
  final subtitles = [
    "我去，额度这么高？",
    "XX，你上次给我兑换的烤箱还不错哦",
    "抱歉，我觉得我们不是很合适",
    "邻居你好，你家的租户最近有点吵"
  ];
  final date = ["昨天 18:08", "星期二", "7月21日", "7月19日"];
  final avatar = [
    "WechatIMG325.jpeg",
    "WechatIMG326.jpeg",
    "WechatIMG327.jpeg",
    "WechatIMG328.jpeg"
  ];
  var color = Colors.white;

  // final icons = [Icons.ac_unit, Icons.access_alarm, Icons.access_time];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ...List.generate(titles.length, (index) {
          return GestureDetector(
            behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
            onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) {
              setState(() {
                color = Colors.grey;
              });
              debugPrint("presed GestureDetector");
            },
            onTapUp: (TapUpDetails details) {
              setState(() {
                color = Colors.white;
              });
              debugPrint("presed GestureDetector");
            },
            child: Container(
              color: color,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
              child: Row(children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 50,
                  child: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10),
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                      child: Image.asset("assets/images/${avatar[index]}",
                          height: 50, width: 50),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                //const SizedBox(width: 10),
                IntrinsicWidth(
                  child: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          titles[index],
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 5),
                        Text(
                          subtitles[index],
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15,
                            color: Colors.black54,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
            ),
          );
        }),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The code above should work as our state is extracted outside of the `build` method and it would update correctly with each `setState`.

Comment: According to your modification, when an item is clicked, the background color of all items has changed，which is not the result I want